# ‘RGoogleTrends’

Tags: r

I am trying to install the  package `‘RGoogleTrends’` in `R` but it says package `‘RGoogleTrends’` is not available (for R version 2.15.2). Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you can install a package with `install.packages` by name alone, it means the package is stored in CRAN (the Comprehensive R Archive Network). Packages have to meet certain quality standards before being admitted to CRAN. While some packages are in a state of development, they may be only available in source form from the author's website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst it may not be available via `install.package('RGoogleTrends', repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")`, you can download the package tar file http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleTrends/RGoogleTrends_0.2-1.tar.gz and install from 
the downloaded file, something like

`install.packages("~/Downloads/RGoogleTrends_0.2-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

replacing the path with the path on your system.

Note that RGoogleTrends imports the packages

RCurl, RSQLite, DBI

You may need to separately install these packages (with repos set to an appropriate non NULL value)

Comment: And it's probably worth pointing out that you'll have to install any of RGoogleTrends' dependencies first.

Comment: True -- RCurl, RSQLite, DBI  were already installed on my machine so it wasn't an issue